# How can I generate all permutations of length n from a set of k elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation, variable-assignment, heaps-algorithm

For example I have this set `k=5` of elements `[1,2,3,4,5]` and I want all permutations of length `n=2`.

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
2,1
etc etc.
```

Thing is I can't use STL, external math libraries etc.

What I tried is generating all permutations of all the elements using Heap's algorithm, and then all the permutations of n elements where contained in the first n numbers of all k-permutations and I could just truncate and delete duplicates, but then the complexity is way too high(n!)

I know the problem has a good solution as I've seen this being done with extra modules/libraries in questions about permutating strings.

Extra info: I only need this to brute force an unbalanced assignment problem, and Hungarian algorithm seems way too long when I'm allowed to "brute-force" the problem. My approach didn't come close to the allowed execution time because when I have an array of for example size 8x3, my algorithm needs 8! comparisons when it definitely could be optimized to a much smaller number.

Comment: a brute force is just two nested loops that pick all possible pairs of elements, that would be `N^2`, I don't get how you arrive at `8!`... better show your attempt, but then actually code reviews belong to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is the only constraint `n=2`, or is `n` any positive integer < k?

Comment: well ok I understood how the `8!` comes about, but thats really wasteful. You have `6!` "duplicates" (ie permutations that have the first two elements the same) and only 8*7 different ones

Comment: *Thing is i can't use STL, external math libraries etc.* -- What would you have done if you could use STL, especially the algorithm functions such as `std::next_permutation`?  Whatever you would have done, just implement it yourself -- it maybe would not have been easy, but at least you would have idea of what to do.

Comment: n is any positive integer < k , i'll check out the next_permutation implementation, thank you for the suggestion :)

And yes, my current implementation is super-wasteful, thats why i gave up and asked for help, because thats the best i came up with.

Comment: The trick with these questions that state that you can't use STL is to first write your program using STL.  Then once you see that the idea you came up with actually works, then you replace all the STL with your home-made code.  Use STL to quickly prototype your solution first.

Comment: Isn't the total number of items you're looking for is `C(k,n) * P(n)`, where `C(k,n)` is the combination of k items taken n at a time, and `P(n)` is the number of permutations for n items?  If so, then you should be first working on a combination generator, and for every combination generated, a permutation generator.  There is an ample supply of combination generation and permutation generation functions written in C++ that do not use STL.  One way of generating combinations is to use a parallel array of bools, and for each combination, the bools are adjusted to generate the next combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it in two steps, first, generate combination of k elements out of a set of n, then print permutation of each combination. I tested this code and works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArr(int a[], int n, bool newline = true) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (i > 0) cout << ",";
        cout << a[i];
    }
    if (newline) cout << endl;
}

// Generating permutation using Heap Algorithm
void heapPermutation(int a[], int n, int size) {
    // if size becomes 1 then prints the obtained permutation
    if (size == 1) {
        printArr(a, n);
        return;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        heapPermutation(a, n, size-1);
        // if size is odd, swap first and last element, otherwise swap ith and last element
        swap(a[size%2 == 1 ? 0 : i], a[size-1]);
    }
}

// Generating permutation using Heap Algorithm
void heapKPermutation(int a[], int n, int k, int size) {
    // if size becomes 1 then prints the obtained permutation
    if (size == n - k + 1) {
        printArr(a + n - k, k);
        return;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        heapKPermutation(a, n, k, size-1);
        // if size is odd, swap first and last element, otherwise swap ith and last element
        swap(a[size%2 == 1 ? 0 : i], a[size-1]);
    }
}

void doKCombination(int a[], int n, int p[], int k, int size, int start) {
    int picked[size + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) picked[i] = p[i];
    if (size == k) {
        // We got a valid combination, use the heap permutation algorithm to generate all permutations out of it.
        heapPermutation(p, k, k);
    } else {
        if (start < n) {
            doKCombination(a, n, picked, k, size, start + 1);
            picked[size] = a[start];
            doKCombination(a, n, picked, k, size + 1, start + 1);
        }
    }
}

// Generate combination of k elements out of a set of n
void kCombination(int a[], int n, int k) {
    doKCombination(a, n, nullptr, k, 0, 0);
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    cout << "n=1, k=1, a=";
    printArr(a, 1);
    kCombination(a, 1, 1);

    cout << "n=2, k=1, a=";
    printArr(a, 2);
    kCombination(a, 2, 1);

    cout << "n=3, k=2, a=";
    printArr(a, 3);
    kCombination(a, 3, 2);

    cout << "n=5, k=2, a=";
    printArr(a, 5);
    kCombination(a, 5, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
n=1, k=1, a=1
1
n=2, k=1, a=1,2
2
1
n=3, k=2, a=1,2,3
2,3
3,2
1,3
3,1
1,2
2,1
n=5, k=2, a=1,2,3,4,5
4,5
5,4
3,5
5,3
3,4
4,3
2,5
5,2
2,4
4,2
2,3
3,2
1,5
5,1
1,4
4,1
1,3
3,1
1,2
2,1
```

Comment: Hey, unfortunately i came to this exact same solution on my own through sweat and tears because i did not see your response. 

Still THANK YOU very very much, i was very satisfied with this solution its simple, elegant and i feel dumb i didnt come up with faster :>

Answer (score 1):

In practice, you have `k` possibilities for the first value.

Then, once you have selected this first value, the problem is to generate all permutations with `n-1` and `k-1` parameters.

This lead to a rather simple recursive implementation. There may be faster methods. However, it is clearly faster than your algorithm.

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <algorithm>

bool Pnk (int n, int k, int *a, int iter, int offset) {

    if (n == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    bool check = true;
    int index = 0;
    std::swap (a[iter], a[iter+offset]);
    while (check) {
        if (n-1 == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= iter; ++i) {
                std::cout << a[i] << " ";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        check = Pnk (n-1, k-1, a, iter + 1, index);
        index++;
    }
    std::swap (a[iter], a[iter+offset]);
    return offset != k-1;
}

void Pnk0 (int n, int k, int *a) {
    int offset = 0;
    while (Pnk (n, k, a, 0, offset)) {
        offset++;
    }
}

int main () {
    int length = 3;
    const int size = 4;
    int a[size] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    Pnk0 (length, size, a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about output being in lexicographic order here's a fairly straightforward implementation.

```
using namespace std;

void perm(int* a, int n, int k, int i)
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
        for(int j=n; j<n+k; j++) cout << a[j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }

    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        swap(a[j], a[n-1]);
        perm(a, n-1, k, i-1);
        swap(a[j], a[n-1]);
    }

}
```

Test ([OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/HyzjJDAK8)):

```
int n = 4, k = 2;
int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
perm(a, n, k, k);
```

Output:

```
4 1 
2 1 
3 1 
1 2 
4 2 
3 2 
1 3 
2 3 
4 3 
1 4 
2 4 
3 4
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if n is always 2, but if it is and you don't mind performance, here's some """working""" code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::tuple<int, int> >
get_tuples_from_vector (const std::vector<int> elements)
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, int> > tuples;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < elements.size(); ++j)
        {
            tuples.push_back({elements[i], elements[j]});
        }
    }
    return tuples;
}

std::vector<std::tuple<int, int> >
generate_permutations (const std::vector<int>& elements)
{
    if (elements.size() == 0 || elements.size() < 2)
    {
        return {};
    }

    std::vector<std::tuple<int, int> > tuples
    { 
        get_tuples_from_vector(elements) 
    };

    std::vector<std::tuple<int, int> > permutations;

    for (const auto& tuple: tuples)
    {
        permutations.push_back(
            { std::get<0>(tuple), std::get<1>(tuple) }
        );
        permutations.push_back(
            { std::get<1>(tuple), std::get<0>(tuple) }
        );
    }

    return permutations;
}

void print_vector(std::vector<std::tuple<int, int> > elements)
{
    for (const auto& element: elements)
    {
        std::cout << "[ " 
            << std::get<0>(element) 
            << ", " << std::get<1>(element) 
            << "]\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    print_vector(generate_permutations({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but i can neither use STL nor is n always equal to 2.

Nevertheless i'll go through the code, theres always something to learn from similiar problems :)

Comment: Not even for vectors? Damn that seems silly. Also, although Functional Programming in C++ is not very efficient, you could check some approach based on that to do the permutations. See https://github.com/shaunluttin/algorithms/blob/master/articles/functional-programs-for-generating-permutations/article.pdf