# Finding all subsets of specified size

Tags: algorithm, set, subset

I've been scratching my head about this for two days now and I cannot come up with a solution. What I'm looking for is a function `f(s, n)` such that it returns a set containing all subsets of `s` where the length of each subset is `n`.

Demo:

```
s={a, b, c, d}

f(s, 4)
{{a, b, c, d}}

f(s, 3) 
{{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, c, d}, {b, c, d}}

f(s, 2)
{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}, {b, c}, {b, d}, {c, d}}

f(s, 1)
{{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}}
```

I have a feeling that recursion is the way to go here. I've been fiddling with something like

```
f(S, n):
   for s in S:
       t = f( S-{s}, n-1 ) 
       ...
```

But this does not seem to do the trick. I did notice that `len(f(s,n))` seems to be the binomial coefficient `bin(len(s), n)`. I guess this could be utilized somehow.

Can you help me please?

Comment: The search term would be "find subset permutations", something like that. Some languages like C++ have built-in library support. Yes, mathematically this could be a recursive algorithm. How to best implement it practically in a certain language is another story.

Comment: This seems  rather similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592209/how-can-i-generate-all-permutations-of-length-n-from-a-set-of-k-elements/61599670#61599670

Comment: I think they are looking for combinations of length `n` since their results are unordered tuples @Lundin

Comment: @Lundin and Damien. If I'm not wrong, permutations are ordered, which sets are not.

Comment: It's the same algorithm regardless. The advantage of sets is that you have no duplicates, as opposed to for example algorithms for finding all sub strings of a string. Also in practice I don't quite see how you can implement a set in a feasible way without sorting it, or adding/removing will be terribly inefficient. C++ `std::set` for example, comes with a mandatory sorting order and you must define a way to compare items of the set in advance, in order to use the container class.

Comment: @klutt You are right, sets are not ordered. In practice, this implies that you can basically use the same kind of algorithms, except that they are simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us call `n` the size of the array and `k` the number of elements to be out in a subarray.

Let us consider the first element `A[0]` of the array `A`.
If this element is put in the subset, the problem becomes a `(n-1, k-1)` similar problem.
If not, it becomes a `(n-1, k)` problem.

This can be simply implemented in a recursive function.

We just have to pay attention to deal with the extreme cases `k == 0` or `k > n`.

During the process, we also have to keep trace of:

- n: the number of remaining elements of A to consider
- k: the number of elements that remain to be put in the current subset
- index: the index of the next element of A to consider
- The `current_subset` array that memorizes the elements already selected.

  Here is a simple code in c++ to illustrate the algorithm

*Output*

For 5 elements and subsets of size 3:

```
3 4 5
2 4 5
2 3 5
2 3 4
1 4 5
1 3 5
1 3 4
1 2 5
1 2 4
1 2 3
```

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <vector>

void print (const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& subsets) {
    for (auto &v: subsets) {
        for (auto &x: v) {
            std::cout << x << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
//  n: number of remaining elements of A to consider
//  k: number of elements that remain to be put in the current subset
//  index: index of next element of A to consider

void Get_subset_rec (std::vector<std::vector<int>>& subsets, int n, int k, int index, std::vector<int>& A, std::vector<int>& current_subset) {
    if (n < k) return;   
    if (k == 0) {
        subsets.push_back (current_subset);
        return;
    }  
    Get_subset_rec (subsets, n-1, k, index+1, A, current_subset);
    current_subset.push_back(A[index]);
    Get_subset_rec (subsets, n-1, k-1, index+1, A, current_subset);
    current_subset.pop_back();         // remove last element
    return;
}

void Get_subset (std::vector<std::vector<int>>& subsets, int subset_length, std::vector<int>& A) {
    std::vector<int> current_subset;
    Get_subset_rec (subsets, A.size(), subset_length, 0, A, current_subset);
}

int main () {
    int subset_length = 3;     // subset size
    std::vector A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int size = A.size();
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> subsets;

    Get_subset (subsets, subset_length, A);
    std::cout << subsets.size() << "\n";
    print (subsets);
}
```

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/K-KpQqgzLq)

Comment: I tried to implement this i Java, but I failed. I would be grateful if you could help me out. https://stackoverflow.com/q/70976317/6699433

Comment: @klutt I don't know java, but I will have a look.

Comment: Don't exhaust yourself in that case

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is by backtracking. Here's a possible algorithm in pseudo code:

```
def backtrack(input_set, idx, partial_res, res, n):
  if len(partial_res == n):
    res.append(partial_res[:])
    return
  
  for i in range(idx, len(input_set)):
    partial_res.append(input_set[i])
    backtrack(input_set, idx+1, partial_res, res, n) # path with input_set[i]
    partial_res.pop()
    backtrack(input_set, idx+1, partial_res, res, n) # path without input_set[i]
```

Time complexity of this approach is `O(2^len(input_set))` since we make 2 branches at each element of `input_set`, regardless of whether the path leads to a valid result or not. The space complexity is `O(len(input_set) choose n)` since this is the number of valid subsets you get, as you correctly pointed out in your question.

Now, there is a way to optimize the above algorithm to reduce the time complexity to `O(len(input_set) choose n)` by pruning the recursive tree to paths that can lead to valid results only.

If `n - len(partial_res) < len(input_set) - idx + 1`, we are sure that even if we took every remaining element in `input_set[idx:]` we are still short at least one to reach `n`. So we can employ this as a base case and return and prune.

Also, if `n - len(partial_res) == len(input_set) - idx + 1`, this means that we need each and every element in `input_set[idx:]` to get the required `n` length result. Thus, we can't skip any elements and so the second branch of our recursive call becomes redundant.

```
backtrack(input_set, idx+1, partial_res, res, n) # path without input_set[i]
```

We can skip this branch with a conditional check.
Implementing these base cases correctly, reduces the time complexity of the algorithm to `O(len(input_set) choose k)`, which is a hard limit because that's the number of subsets that there are.

Answer (score 1):

```
subseqs 0 _      = [[]]
subseqs k []     = []
subseqs k (x:xs) = map (x:) (subseqs (k-1) xs) ++ subseqs k xs
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hdcdvMPWq)

The function looks for subsequences of (non-negative) length k in a given sequence. There are three cases:

1. If the length is 0: there is a single empty subsequence in any sequence.
2. Otherwise, if the sequence is empty: there are no subsequences of any (positive) length k.
3. Otherwise, there is a non-empty sequence that starts with `x` and continues with `xs`, and a positive length `k`. All our subsequences are of two kinds: those that contain `x` (they are subsequences of `xs` of length `k-1`, with `x` stuck at the front of each one), and those that do not contain `x` (they are just subsequences of `xs` of length `k`).

The algorithm is a more or less literal translation of these notes to Haskell. Notation cheat sheet:

- `[]` an empty list
- `[w]` a list with a single element `w`
- `x:xs` a list with a head of `x` and a tail of `xs`
- `(x:)` a function that sticks an `x` in front of any list
- `++` list concatenation
- `f a b c` a function `f` applied to arguments `a` `b` and `c`

Comment: FP always seems like magic to me :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-recursive python function that takes a list `superset` and returns a generator that produces all subsets of size `k`.

```
def subsets_k(superset, k):
  if k > len(superset):
    return
  if k == 0:
    yield []
    return

  indices = list(range(k))
  while True:
    yield [superset[i] for i in indices]

    i = k - 1
    while indices[i] == len(superset) - k + i:
      i -= 1
      if i == -1:
        return
    
    indices[i] += 1
    for j in range(i + 1, k):
      indices[j] = indices[i] + j - i
```

Testing it:

```
for s in subsets_k(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 3):
  print(s)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'e']
['a', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'c', 'e']
['a', 'd', 'e']
['b', 'c', 'd']
['b', 'c', 'e']
['b', 'd', 'e']
['c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Statement:**
For given one dimesional array of numbers find all possible subsets
of that array with specific length.e.g.
For Array [1,2,3] If we want to find all subsets of length 2 then
Output should be

```
[
  [1,2],
  [1,3],
  [2,3]
]
```

**Solution:**

```
function getAllSubsetsOfSpecificLength(array, length) {
  const subsets = [[]];
  const subsetsOfSpecificLength = [];

  for (const el of array) {
    const last = subsets.length - 1;
    for (let i = 0; i <= last; i++) {
      let set = [...subsets[i], el];
      subsets.push(set);

      if (set.length == length) {
        subsetsOfSpecificLength.push(set);
      }

      if (set.length > length) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return subsetsOfSpecificLength;
}
let array = [1, 2, 3];
let result = getAllSubsetsOfSpecificLength(array, 2);
console.log(result);
```

**Output:**

```
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 3 ] ]
```